# How to pass the current user from the Api layer to service layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, n-tier-architecture

in the WebApi I can get the current user using AspIdentity that way

```
User.Identity.GetUserId<long>();
```

However, The service Layer doesn't know about the AspIdentity. And I don't want to passe the current user as paramettre for all the methodes.

In other word, what pattern I can use to get the current user wherever I want.

The reason for this is to log all the activity the current user is doing in the application.

Comment: It doesn't need to know about `AspIdentity`. You could pass the `IPrincipal` retrieved from `User` higher up down through to lower layers. Otherwise the only thing left is to use the static `HttpContext` which would be an anti-pattern of sorts.

Comment: @Nkosi isn't there a common way to do that? Like using this System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current? my related question I'm researching https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53092899/i-cant-access-my-logged-in-user-in-my-data-access-layer-identity-server-4-and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is how I implemented it.

In the Framework Layer (a comun independent project) I added this:

```
public interface ICurrentContextProvider<T>
{
    T GetCurrentUser();      
}
```

In the API I Added the implementation of this interface, something like :

```
public  ApplicationUser GetCurrentUser()
{
     return _usersService.FindByIdAsync(Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId())).Result;
}
```

And As the all other layers know about the Framework Layer I can call it anywhere without any reference to AspIdentity and without passing the Current user to all my functions.

Note: I make it a generic because of the following:
1-Framework (common layer) doesn't know about application user
2-I can get any other type from the context like the ApplicationUserId which is Long.

Answer (score 1):

APIs are intended to be stateless, you *may* use the current logged in user, but you may have a 3rd party application accessing your API.  Because it is stateless the current user is handled differently than with standard web calls.

Long story short: however you're authenticating your API users, you need to pass the username/userID down into the service layer.  The good news is that once you have this setup, you can use the same service layer methods for API and non-API calls.